what is the minimum number of pencils that he must select in order to ensure that he selects at least 2 pencils of each color?
Ben has 40 pencils in a box. Each of the pencils is one of 5 different colors, and there are 8
pencils of each color. If Ben selects pencils one at a time from the box without being able to see the
pencils, what is the minimum number of pencils that he must select in order to ensure that he selects
at least 2 pencils of each color?
The answer is 8+8+8+8+1=33 answer=33+1
The maximum number that this condition (to ensure that he selects
at least 2 pencils of each color) is not true is considered 33, but it is not understandable fore me because I think even in 8+8+8+8+1 condition still is the chance to 2 of pencils be the same color....
Now for minimum number that 2 pencils are the same color is 33+1

The minimum would be 10, any less and it would be impossible.

@cheesewiz:  that is the minimum that he could select and possibly get two of each color.  The question asks the minimum that he could select and be sure to get two of each color.  If he picks $10$ he could get $8$ of one color and $2$ of another and not have any of three colors.

@cheesewiz:  No, it takes $34$.  If he only takes $33$ he could take all $32$ of four colors and one of the fifth.

That is correct, now it is understandable for me. By choosing 8+8+8+8+2 is the condition which at least 2 of chosen pencils are from each color.

I think the easiest way to see it is to focus on one color.  Say $8$ of the $40$ pencils are red.  How many must he select to be sure of having two red ones?  There are $32$ non-red pencils and he could select all of them first.  After that, there are only red ones left and two more selections makes sure he has two red ones.  As the colors are symmetric this applies to all the other colors as well.
